# Google Maps: run 2 scripts at the same time to display markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am developing this small tool that reads 2 XML files that have some information about certain positions in Google Maps in the sequence (id, interval, lat, lng).

The first file contains real GPS data and the second contains corrected GPS data after I applied some algorithm.

Now I want to represent these 2 sets as markers on the same map like this:
P1 from file1 and P1 from file2 at the same time.. then after some time display P2 from file1 and P2 from file2 together... and so on.

This is the Javascript code that I wrote to display one of the sets:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var id = null;
var timestamp = null;
var lat = null;
var lng = null;

var locations = new Array();    

loadXMLFile();

function loadXMLFile()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'data2.xml' ,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXML,
        error : function(ts) { alert("Error: " + ts.responseStatus) }
    });
}

function parseXML(xml)
{
    $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
        id = $(this).find('id').text();
        timestamp = $(this).find('ts').text();
        lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        lng = $(this).find('lng').text();

        locations.push([parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng)]);

    });
    marker(0);
}

function marker(i){
if (i > locations.length) return;
    var marker;

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
    });

    setTimeout("marker("+(i+1)+")", 500);
}
```

I read that Javascript does not support multithreading.. I also tried using web workers but it didn't work (or I couldn't make it work because I'm new to Javascript and HTML).
I hope I can find help to get to display the 2 sets of markers at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you geocodezip for your answer, but I managed to do it somehow..

I read the 2 XML files, stored each one in an array, then combined the 2 arrays in one array, then in the marker() function i displayed 2 entries at a time from the combined array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a task that runs periodically (setInterval).  Display the "next" marker when that runs.  Start it running after all the data (both sets) is loaded.